# My code in C# for a simple currency conversion program won't work properly for me

Tags: c#

The code is just an exercise for college to convert Euros to Dollars but I just can't figure out why it won't work. I've included the code here. I added in an extra Console.ReadLine(); myself so that I could find out what the answer was. This is because if I only have the one, the program just starts and then finishes in a flash. The answer always seems to be 54.88.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT:* I accidentally put "Enter Dollars" instead of "Enter Euros." This shouldn't have affected the code, just the wording. Garbage in, Garbage out is what happened to me possibly though.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace euro_to_dollar
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float dollars, conversion_rate, euros;
            conversion_rate = 1.12f;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in Dollars:");
            dollars = Console.Read();
            euros = dollars * conversion_rate;
            Console.WriteLine("Dollars:" + euros);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what your input is like? What are you putting for "Enter in Dollars:"? No matter what you put, it spits out 54.88?

Comment: `Console.Read` reads in one character and gives you its encoded value. You want `Console.ReadLine` and `float.Parse` instead.  Note that the ASCII code for `'1'` is `49` and `49 * 1.12 = 54.88`.

Comment: Have you placed breakpoints at the top of the application and stepped through each line to see what the values are as it executes?

Comment: Use `Console.ReadLine()`, not `Console.Read()`, and parse it to a float: `dollars = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Shouldn't dollars = Console.Read(); be dollars = Console.ReadLine();?

Comment: all of these other comments about ReadLine are correct, but additionally, if the exchange rate is meant to be based on reality, should be dividing by that exchange rate, not multiplying. there are about 1.12 Dollars per euro, not 1.12 Euros per Dollar

Comment: Note that most mistakes students are about to make are already present on SO: I.e. the exact problem you are facing (closed as duplicate) found by following search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20Console.Read%20double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) only reads one character from the console.

Instead the code should use `dollars = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

So the complete code would be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace euro_to_dollar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float dollars, conversion_rate, euros;
            conversion_rate = 1.12f;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in Dollars:");
            dollars = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            euros = dollars * conversion_rate;
            Console.WriteLine("Dollars:" + euros);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The reason you were getting 54.88 every time is because every time you tested a number, it started with the character `1`, which is represented with the number `49` in ASCII. Thus, `1.12 * 49 = 54.88`

Comment: Of course if someone types "ABC" instead of numbers the code will fail again.

Comment: I reckon that this is the most helpful answer because it's still using most of my original code. We're not supposed to use anything more than that really because we've only just started C#. Thanks for your help mate! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply use `float.TryParse()`:

```
string dollars = Console.ReadLine();
float dollarsValue;
bool isConversionSuccessful = float.TryParse(dollars, out dollarsValue);

if (isConversionSuccessful) {
    ...
}
```

`.TryParse()` will parse the value of `dollars` and bind it to `dollarsValue` if it succeeds. The method also returns a bool value, so you can use that for some additional checks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to convert the initial `string` input (from `Console.ReadLine()`) into money type representation (usually `decimal`). Do not mix `Console.Read()` which reads just a *character* and `Console.ReadLine()` which reads the *entire string*:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // conversion_rate is a constant (at least in this program)
        const decimal conversion_rate = 1.12m;
        // decimal is a preferable type for money
        decimal dollars = 0.00m; 

        // ask until correct value is entered
        do 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in Dollars:");
        } // Console.ReadLine() - we want entire string (e.g. "5.31") not just '5' char
        while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dollars));    

        // use formatting
        Console.WriteLine("Dollars: {0} are equal to {1} euros", 
          dollars, dollars * conversion_rate);

        // do you really want two pauses? (two Console.ReadLine())
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The right result for today is 1$ = 0.89€

Comment: This helped me in realising the difference between Console.Read and Console.ReadLine! I also realised I actually wrote it wrong in that I was supposed to have "Enter in Dollars" as "Enter in Euros". My mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Like other say in the comments you this is the code you have to use ( the key is user Console.ReadLine instead of Console.Read

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace euro_to_dollar
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float dollars, conversion_rate, euros;
        conversion_rate = 1.12f;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter in Dollars:");
        dollars = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        euros = dollars * conversion_rate;
        Console.WriteLine("Dollars:" + euros);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `this is the code you have to use` I would never use it....

Comment: Again, if you really want to give an answer based on the comments already posted above, at least try to be helpful resolving the other problems of that code

Comment: BTW: don't multiply *string* by *float* :)

Comment: My bad i just edit the answer with the right result.

Comment: The right result for today is 1$  = 0.89€